# Mythtv 0.25 rescan for videos

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I have been searching for instructions regarding rescanning the /var/lib/mythtv/video folder. Most instructions are dated and reference older mythtv versions. Some note that mythvideo has been 'pulled into' the mythcore with version 0.25. I am running 0.25. How do I rescan for new videos (*.mkv and/or *.avi) within the above mentioned video path?

Answer (score 0):

When in MythVideo, hit M, then 'Scan for changes'.

Comment: Is there a command line way to do this?

Comment: Searching pays off. In my case I am running Mythbuntu headless and do not have a keyboard attached. Via ssh I can run 'mythutil --scanvideos' and it triggers a re-scan of all video directories. Please tag this as "SOLVED". Thank you.